# Need references of equations between different HTML pages with htlatex

Tags: html, latex, mathjax

I would like to convert a big TeX source using `htlatex` into HTML pages. The TeX file contains equations formatted with Mathjax. For this purpose, and from [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261350/equations-are-unchanged-with-verbatim-package), I am using the following config.cfg :

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\Preamble{xhtml}
% Configure for mathjax
\Configure{VERSION}{}
\Configure{DOCTYPE}{\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{HTML}{\HCode{<html>\Hnewline}}{\HCode{\Hnewline</html>}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">                                           
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    TeX: {           
      Macros: {     
        \unexpanded{ bt: ['{\$\\mathb\{\#1\}\$}',1], 
                     beq: ['{\\mathbf\{\#1\}}',1],}
             }
       },
    extensions: ["AMSmath.js"], 
    equationNumbers: {autoNumber: "AMS"},
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"], 
    tex2jax: {       
        \unexpanded{
      inlineMath: [ ['\$','\$'], ["\\\\(","\\\\)"] ],
      displayMath: [ ['\\begin{displaymath}','\\end{displaymath}'], ['\\begin{equation}','\\end{equation}'], ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],}
      processEscapes: true
      }
  });
</script>   
}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<script type="text/javascript"\Hnewline
src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"\Hnewline
></script>\Hnewline}}

\newtoks\eqtoks 
\def\AltMath#1${\eqtoks{$#1$}% 
   \HCode{\the\eqtoks}$}
\Configure{$}{}{}{\expandafter\AltMath}  
\def\AltlMathI#1\){\eqtoks{\(#1\)}% 
        \HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
\Configure{()}{\AltlMathI}{}
\def\AltlDisplay#1\]{\eqtoks{\[#1\]}%
        \HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
\Configure{[]}{\AltlDisplay}{}
\begin{document} 
\newcommand\VerbMath[1]{%
\renewenvironment{#1}{%
\NoFonts%
\string\begin\{#1\}%
\verbatim}{\endverbatim\string\end\{#1\}\EndNoFonts}%
}
\VerbMath{equation}
\VerbMath{equation*}
\VerbMath{cases}
\VerbMath{array}
\VerbMath{matrix}
\VerbMath{pmatrix}
\VerbMath{eqnarray}
\VerbMath{eqnarray*}
\EndPreamble
```

Here is the command that I use to generate HTML pages (with 3rd level) :

```
htlatex document.tex "config,3"
```

Unfortunately, the equations are not referenced and I don't know how to do this. May this issue come from the fact that there are multiple HTML pages being generated?

Moreover, some equation references are not in the HTML page where they are defined with `\label`. Is there a trick to achieve this?

Comment: You might want to add a minimal example of the resulting html.

Comment: you can get in the update section of my question above a link showing an example of generated HTML pages

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.